# Show me how to a start a background process and then be able to kill it at later time

Tags: linux, debian

Can someone please show me an example of starting a simple background process on the command line; and then later maybe have to open a new command line and then kill the background process?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Raspberry Pi per se; it's a general Unix/Linux question. It's also very easy to find the answer by googling `run process in the background`. You'll find hundreds of examples, including [this one](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afnz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run a process in the background with the `&` at the end. After you started the process, you can get the process number (pid) with `$!`. later you can use that process number to kill the process.

```
sleep 60 &
SLEEP_PID=$!
sleep 2
kill $SLEEP_PID
```

If you want to use the pid in another shell, you need to save it to a file.

```
sleep 3600
echo $! > /tmp/pidfile

kill $(cat /tmp/pidfile)
```